# JPA Repository - combination of and, or conditions

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a query with a combination of and, or conditions in it

in SQL it looks like select * from users where id = 5 and (name like 'Joe' or last_name like 'Rose')
how can I do it in JPA Repository, I prefer not to use @Query, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
List<User> findByNameContainingOrLastNameContainingAndId(String name, String lastName, Long id);
```

Comment: it would be equal to select * from users where name like 'Joe' or (last_name like 'Rose' and id = 5) , wouln't it? in any case what if I have some of and or is there any why to use a kind of parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, correct. And has higher precedence than Or. So, I guess, can be done only with @Query.